# JavaScript: why does onbeforeunload fire twice on this page and how to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

On this url http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/doctor/Seattle,%20WA, I open up console and copy paste

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) { return "Are you sure?"; };
```

and click on 'The Myo Clinic' and it ends up warning me twice. Any reasons to why?

When I click anywhere else but the link, it will warn me only once.

Why is this firing twice and how can I force it to fire only once?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me. No matter what I click, I get warned once

Comment: @Ian, try hitting stay on page i get the two warnings but only by hitting the stay on page option, in chrome anyway

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yeah, I tried both the "leave" and "stay" options, and I'm also on Chrome, but I'm only ever warned once

Comment: @Ian when you click the main link in the records, it will fire twice if you choose to stay on the current page.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue on some of my code.  Even tried incognito mode in case it was an extension.